# React-share: Pintrest share button not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, libraries, react-share, socialsharing-plugin

i am using react-share library version 5.0.3.
i have used pintrest share button but it just opening pintrest page but the shared image is not getting attached there.

sample code:

```
let link = https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg

    <PinterestShareButton media={link} url={link}>
            <PinterestIcon size={35} round={true} />
    </PinterestShareButton>
```

on pintrest it just shows like this
[image]

How to resolve this or what can be the fix.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? If there are, can you attach the same here

Comment: @HarshaVenkataramu there are no error just that window opens and noting else

Comment: Does it meet the criteria set by the pinterest plugin?

Comment: @HarshaVenkataramu yes according to me every thing is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by giving description prop to the pintrest button component line this

```
<PinterestShareButton
          url={link}
          media={link}
         description={"description of the image"}
        >
```

And then it will open image attached pintrest popup.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a working button. Could you please check if it's what you need?

[code](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/react-share-demo-forked-m6tmw2?workspaceId=8344d90a-1a13-4ba0-9f8c-bb7cd5a90a8a&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50007356icgv5fwxi%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50002356i25ka4ld8%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50004356i1v8m8rqn%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50006356iccv4oopw%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cls48qik50002356i25ka4ld8%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50001356i9bj8p71t%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50002356i25ka4ld8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50001356i9bj8p71t%2522%257D%252C%2522cls48qik50006356iccv4oopw%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50005356i1l3v415z%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50006356iccv4oopw%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50005356i1l3v415z%2522%257D%252C%2522cls48qik50004356i1v8m8rqn%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50003356ibgyke9o4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50004356i1v8m8rqn%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls48qik50003356ibgyke9o4%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: no your code is also not working you just click on button it will open pintrest popup but the image is not attached there we have to attach image manualy in that popup

Comment: It is working for me if possible send me the code snippet so that I can run and check.

Comment: its not working it will just add the pintrest page but the image will not get attached by itself to do so you need to add description prop to Pintrest button and it will be fixed.

Comment: <PinterestShareButton
          url={link}
          media={link}
          className="Demo__some-network__share-button"
        >
I shared u the same thing but u are not able to understand I think

Comment: just add discription tag to you component and you can see the difference by youself
line

just replace you component with this
<PinterestShareButton
          url={link}
          media={link}
         description={"description of the image"}
        >

Comment: yea added nothing changed.

Comment: are you sure there is not :))) 
checkout this video you will know 
https://www.loom.com/share/709d0e07a26f4f6cba97685cd593f4a4?sid=66f564e5-125b-4061-b965-cfeb91660fb6